# How to Return a Stored Value in Inner text using php

Tags: php

PHP Code:

```
$name = 'click here';

echo '<a href="http://example.net/some.php" class="menu">$name</a>';
```

Here I am Expecting 'Click here' but my Output is:

```
$name
```

Comment: Swap over the single quotes to double quotes, and vice versa.

Comment: [_sigh_ read the basics !](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: Use " double quotes not single quotes around your echo statement. You also need to use \" for the quotes within your echo statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) addresses this accurately:

> Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters **will not** be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

To solve the issue, use either one of these solutions:

```
echo "<a href=\"http://example.net/some.php\" class=\"menu\">$name</a>"; 

echo '<a href="http://example.net/some.php" class="menu">'.$name.'</a>';

<a href="http://example.net/some.php" class="menu"> <?php echo $name; ?> </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use double quotes around your entire `echo` statement and escape the quotes in your HTML, or use the concantination operator `.`

Using double quotes:

```
"<a href=\"http://example.net/some.php\" class=\"menu\">$name</a>";
```

Using the concantination operator

```
'<a href="http://example.net/some.php" class="menu">'.$name.'</a>';
```

Using double quotes causes PHP to evaluate all variables (replace them with their contents) within the string. However to do this you also have to escape the inner double quotes by making them `\"` so that PHP doesn't confuse them with the end of the string.

Using the concantination operator you are actually creating 3 different strings, the open tag, the contents of the variable, and the closing tag and then gluing them together using the `.` to make one complete string which is sent to `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

Manual reference on strings
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

The basics are anything within " (double quotes) is evaluated, anything within ' (single quotes) is not.

So for your code there are a few options

Replace single quotes with double quotes and escape embedded double quotes with \

```
echo "<a href=\"http://example.net/some.php\" class=\"menu\">$name</a>";
```

You can also replace the embedded double quotes with single quotes (i don't think  html minds, not sure about html5)

```
echo "<a href='http://example.net/some.php' class='menu'>$name</a>";
```

You could also do a printf, this replace %s = string, with your value $name

```
printf('<a href="http://example.net/some.php" class="menu">%s</a>", $name);
```